# MSSQL PHP Error: invalid precision value hy104

Tags: php, sql-server, prepared-statement, precision

Have been trying to debug this for hours and no outcome. Please help. 
Environment: PHP5.3 talking to MSSQL2005/8 with Microsoft MSSQL Driver for PHP
SQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Enquiry] ([FullName], [FirstName],  [Surname], [ContactPhone], 
[WorkPhone], [ContactMobile], [EmailAddress],  [Callwhen], [LoanType],  [EnquiryDate],      
[Suburb], [State],  [PostCode], [HiddenField], [CFIssue01], [CFIssue02], [CFIssue03], 
[CFIssue04], [ProductID]) VALUES ('asdf asdf','asdf','asdf','03 12312312','02 12312312',
'','','10:12 AM 02/08/11','CF','2011-08-02 10:12:45',
'asdf','NSW','1231','245678','asdfasdf1222','','','','CF')
```

If I run this query with `sqlsrv_query()` and it works well.

To prevent SQL Injection, I prefer to use prepared statement `sqlsrv_prepare()` and `sqlsrv_execute()`.

To do prepared statement, I have:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Enquiry] ([FullName], [FirstName], [Surname], [ContactPhone],     
[WorkPhone], [ContactMobile], [EmailAddress], [Callwhen], [LoanType], [EnquiryDate], 
[Suburb], [State], [PostCode], [HiddenField], [CFIssue01], [CFIssue02], [CFIssue03], 
[CFIssue04], [ProductID]) VALUES "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)"
```

Then I have params:

```
$params = array( &$mm_fullname, &$mm_firstname,  &$mm_surname,  &$mm_contactphone, 
&$mm_workphone,  &$mm_contactmobile,  &$mm_emailaddress,  &$mm_callwhen,  &$mm_loantype,    
&$mm_enquirydate,  &$mm_suburb,  &$mm_state, &$mm_postcode,  &$mm_hiddenfield,  
&$mm_cfissue01,  &$mm_cfissue02,  &$mm_cfissue03, &$mm_cfissue04, &$mm_productid );
```

Then prepare the statement:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $tsql, $params))
```

Then run the statement:
    `sqlsrv_execute( $stmt)` ......... ban! error here:

```
[0] => HY104
[SQLSTATE] => HY104
[1] => 0
[code] => 0
[2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Invalid precision value
[message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Invalid precision value
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong..

Update #1: convert all params to string - same error:

```
/* Assign parameter values. */
                $mm_fullname = strval($firstname . " " . $lastname);
                $mm_firstname = strval($firstname);
                $mm_surname = strval($lastname);
                $mm_contactphone = strval($homenumber);
                $mm_workphone = strval($worknumber);
                $mm_contactmobile = strval($mobilenumber);
                $mm_emailaddress = strval($email);
                $mm_callwhen = strval(date('h:i A d/m/y'));
                $mm_loantype = strval("CF");
                $mm_enquirydate = strval(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                $mm_suburb = strval($suburb);
                $mm_state = strval($state);
                $mm_postcode = strval($postcode);
                $mm_hiddenfield = strval("245678");
                $mm_cfissue01 = strval($creditissue1);
                $mm_cfissue02 = strval($creditissue2);
                $mm_cfissue03 = strval($creditissue3);
                $mm_cfissue04 = strval($creditissue4);
                $mm_productid = strval("CF");

                $params = array( &$mm_fullname, 
                                 &$mm_firstname, 
                                 &$mm_surname, 
                                 &$mm_contactphone,
                                 &$mm_workphone, 
                                 &$mm_contactmobile, 
                                 &$mm_emailaddress, 
                                 &$mm_callwhen, 
                                 &$mm_loantype, 
                                 &$mm_enquirydate, 
                                 &$mm_suburb, 
                                 &$mm_state, 
                                 &$mm_postcode, 
                                 &$mm_hiddenfield, 
                                 &$mm_cfissue01, 
                                 &$mm_cfissue02, 
                                 &$mm_cfissue03, 
                                 &$mm_cfissue04, 
                                 &$mm_productid );
```

Comment: Except one datetime format field, all the other fields I am inserting are VARCHAR if it helps. The shortest one has VARCHAR(20) and the longest one has VARCHAR(2000).

Comment: Possibly (just guessing) there are some strings getting in there as numbers. Cast your parameters which should be text/strings to strings, to avoid them being interpreted as a number perhaps?

Comment: Hi Wrikken, Thanks for quick response. I tried to use strval() for every params and still same error. Question updated.

Comment: In that case, I'd go for the more wordy option and define all `SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_*`'s for each parameter.

Comment: Thanks Wrikken. I am not sure how to do that yet. I will find out and then test it. Thanks.

Comment: It works! I will put more updates soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Thanks to Wrikken. Your comments worked!

From [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626305.aspx), I found how to define SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_* for each parameter.

Now, I updated my code to have:

```
$params = array(
    array(&$mm_fullname, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(200)),
    array(&$mm_firstname, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(100)),
    array(&$mm_surname, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(100)),
    array(&$mm_contactphone, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(50)),
    array(&$mm_workphone, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(50)),
    array(&$mm_contactmobile, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(50)),
    array(&$mm_emailaddress, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(150)),
    array(&$mm_callwhen, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(50)),
    array(&$mm_loantype, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(50)),
    array(&$mm_enquirydate, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_DATETIME),
    array(&$mm_suburb, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(100)),
    array(&$mm_state, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(50)),
    array(&$mm_postcode, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(20)),
    array(&$mm_hiddenfield, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(2000)),
    array(&$mm_cfissue01, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(2000)),
    array(&$mm_cfissue02, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(2000)),
    array(&$mm_cfissue03, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(2000)),
    array(&$mm_cfissue04, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(2000)),
    array(&$mm_productid, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(50))
);
```

It works great without any error!